# Re-order Query after click on Button - FirestoreRecyclerOptions

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, i can sort my documents in a Query, with it's:

```
query = anuncioRef.orderBy(campo, Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(100);
        options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<AnuncioPrincipal>().setQuery(query,
                AnuncioPrincipal.class).build();
        adapter = new AnuncioAdapter(options);
  RecyclerView recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerCadAnun);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This works fine, but, i need that it change when the user click on button, i need that var "campo" must be changed to "dataPreco" and the list in recycler view must be updated:

```
        botaoFiltrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                campo = "dataAnuncio";

            }
        });
```

In spite of "campo" be changed to "dataAnuncio", the recyclerView still remains equals.

I need that the button click, the recyclerView change to the new query orderBy() method.

Answer (score 1):

The `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` has an [`updateOptions` method](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/firestore/FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java#L104) that you can call to update the options.

So you could call that with something like:

```
query = anuncioRef.orderBy(campo, Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(100); // new campo
options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<AnuncioPrincipal>().setQuery(query, AnuncioPrincipal.class).build();

adapter.updateOptions(options);
```

Comment: the screen blink but nothing happens

Comment: the recycler view remained the same thing

Comment: Check to make sure `campo` has the value you expect it to have.

Comment: Yes, he is changed before adapter.updateOptions(options);